# MVC3 routing with an optional first parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My site is currently set up with the following routes:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "BrandList",
            "Brands",
            new { controller = "Brand", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "BrandProducts",
            "{brand}/Products",
            new { controller = "Brand", action = "Products", manufacturer = "" },
            new { manufacturer = new BrandConstraint() }
        ); 
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Product",
            "{brand}/{partNumber}",
            new { controller = "Product", action = "Details", brand = "" },
            new { manufacturer = new BrandConstraint() }
        );
```

This produces URLs like

```
http://oursite/Brands                     -> List of all brands
http://oursite/SomeBrand                  -> List of one brand's products
http://oursite/SomeBrand/ProductA         -> Details for product
```

I just got the directive, however, that we now need to serve up those same pages on

```
http://oursite/Brands                     -> List of all brands
http://oursite/SomeBrand                  -> List of one brand's products
http://oursite/Brands/SomeBrand           -> List of one brand's products
http://oursite/SomeBrand/ProductA         -> Details for product
http://oursite/Brands/SomeBrand/ProductA  -> Details for product
```

I know I can create two more Routes, identical to the current `BrandProducts` and `Product` routes, with the extra "Brands/" at the beginning.  I'll do that if I need to, but I'd really much prefer to not have to duplicate each route entry (there's more than just these two).

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just try using Url Rewrites instead of adding the complexity of additional routes pointing to the same place.

Also its not good to have multiple canonical formats of URL's that are valid, one should really 301 to the "correct" url.